# running nodejs site in production

Tags: node.js, nginx

I'm working on deploying a nodejs existing project on a server, after some research I've found a number of blog articles recommending using `pm2` to handle keeping the request alive. These are the currently running services on `pm2`

```
[sammy@extendmatch ~]$ pm2 list
┌─────┬───────────────────────────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id  │ name                          │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├─────┼───────────────────────────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 0   │ npm run serve -- --port 80    │ default     │ N/A     │ fork    │ 22626    │ 45s    │ 1696 │ online    │ 0%       │ 30.4mb   │ sammy    │ disabled │
└─────┴───────────────────────────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
```

I'm using the `npm run serve` since this is the same command I use locally to run the project, the `--port` settings is to try and configure the port, initially it runs on port `8080` and as usual the server default port is `80` and that's what I need it to run on.

I'm then linking it to nginx through `\etc\nginx\nginx.conf` with this inclusion on the server section

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 165.22.65.26;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/sammy/webapp/fortnox;
    }
    location /media/ {
        root /home/sammy/webapp/fortnox;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/sammy/webapp/fortnox/fortnox.sock;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:80;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

It's handled by the last `location` rule the others above are for django since it's supposed to provide nodejs with data via api requests. The link on refresh `165.22.65.26` throws a 500 bad gateway. The error log says it either too many files open or can't find the source

```
2020/01/27 03:33:51 [error] 22859#0: *1027 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 165.22.65.26, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://localhost/", host: "165.22.65.26"
2020/01/27 03:33:53 [crit] 22859#0: accept4() failed (24: Too many open files)
```

currently the site doesn't run when using nginx and pm2, I'm not sure if the way I've set it up on one or both are correct, if you've deployed a production ready nodejs site did you go this way if yes do you know how to fix this bug. If you have another way of deploying that can handle traffic well it will also do.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Please edit your question to include a clear and obvious question that you are asking for help with.

Answer (score 0):

Its look like you have both nginx and your nodejs application listening on port 80, generally what you want to do is have nginx listen on port 80 and your nodejs application on some other, usually 4 numbered port like: 8080.

#### So try:

```
npm run serve
```

or

```
npm run serve -- --port 8080
```

#### And change the nginx configuration to

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
```

or

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
```

If you are not sure if your `localhost` is setup properly, it usually is, but in this way you don't have to worry about that possibility.

Reset nginx, and it should work